# Possible uses of a MELF resistor?

Tags: resistors, packages

I have been doing some net-surfing on Farnell's website and stumbled upon a section called

> [MELF Surface Mount Resistors](http://farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=224911)

[image: MELF Resistor]

According to Wikipedia, this package family has a rather funnily sounding de-abbreviation *Most End up Lying on the Floor*, since they are extremely easy to lose. This *may* be due to the fact that they are cylindrical... I myself have lost quite a few of such diodes.

Wiki says, that there are three basic sizes. MELF, MiniMELF, MicroMelf - the two latter are in the power-rating range of 0603/0805 resistors. The 1W MELF package is obviously useful for dissipation reasons.

So my question is, why on Earth would anybody design a board containing small MELF components, since they can easily be replaced with more modern flat parts? I cannot see a single advantage. Please prove me wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The cylindrical construction of MELF
>   devices provides an optimal power rating and pulse load
>   capability related to the mounting space. Continuous
>   development has led to improved long-term stability and
>   moisture resistance, and allows high-temperature operation
>   to + 175 °C.
>
> This paper explores why this resistor series has become so
>   successful, and why there is often no alternative to it today
>   in professional applications.

[Vishay](http://www.vishay.com/docs/28802/melfre.pdf)

Comment: Second Google hit... How could I have missed that...

Comment: Yes, you miss the +1 too. The paper title says `MELF Resistors - The World’s Most Reliable and Predictable, High-Performing Film Resistors` your funny jokes stop :)

Comment: Fair enough....